# Totalview get the value of QString

Tags: c++, debugging, qstring, totalview

[image]

When I double clicked on `QString` object in totalview debugger this window appears. How can I get the exact value of it.

I have tried `command.toUtf8().constData()` but it prints `Cannot find name "toUtf8"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::TV::TTF::RTF::build_struct_transform { 
    name {^struct QString$} 
    members { 
       { ascii { $wstring_u16 cast { * { d -> unicode } } } } 
    } 
} 

::TV::TTF::RTF::build_struct_transform { 
    name {^struct QString$} 
    members { 
       { ascii { $wstring_u16 cast {* {d -> data} } } } 
    } 
}
```

Add this to `$HOME/.tvdrc` flie. First is for `Qt3` and second for `Qt4`.

Answer (score 0):

For QT5 please add the following to the file `$HOME/.tvdrc`

```
::TV::TTF::RTF::build_struct_transform { 
    name {^class QString$}
    members { 
       { string { $wstring_s16 cast {{ * { d }} + 1  } } }     
    } 
}
```