# Get QStringList content in Totalview debugger

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qstring, totalview

In this question [Totalview get the value of QString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959607/totalview-get-the-value-of-qstring) is described how to get `QString` value in totalview debugger. Do you know any way to see the content of `QStringList` too?